# Python Object won't return __dict__ when using __slot__

Tags: python, oop

I have a simple class in here:

```
class Info: 
    # __slots__ = ('name','age')
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age

    def members(self):
        print(self.__dict__)

>>> Info(name= "John", age=10).members()
>>> {'name': 'John', 'age': 10}
```

Now, I add the `__slot__` to the above class:

```
class Info: 
    __slots__ = ('name','age')
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age

    def members(self):
        print(self.__dict__)

Info(name= "John", age=10).members()
```

Now, I keep getting the following error. How am I be able to access objects attributes in this case? Thanks!

```
print(self.__dict__)
AttributeError: 'Info' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Comment: Right that's literally the purpose of `__slots__`. Removing `__dict__` makes objects considerably smaller, so you add a `__slots__` attr on objects you expect to instantiate hundreds or thousands of times

Comment: [... `__slots__` reserves space for the declared variables and prevents the automatic creation of `__dict__` ...](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__slots__#object.__slots__)